# IndexError when iterating over lists using for loops

Tags: python, list

I keep getting an IndexError(list index out of range) when iterating over x and y in the for loop even though the length of x and y are equal. What could I be doing wrong?

```
from math import sqrt
x = []
y = []
distance = []
perimeter = sum(distance)

while True:
   x.append(int(input('Enter x value of a point: ')))
   y.append(int(input('Enter y value of the point: ')))
   if x[-1] == 0 and y[-1] == 0:
      break

for i,j in zip(x, y):
   distance = sqrt((abs((x[i]) - (x[i+1])))**2 + (abs((y[i]) - (y[i+1])))**2)
   if i == len(x):
      break

print(perimeter)
```

Comment: It's in the second for loop. Here i and j are actually values inside x and y, not indices. Just do: for i in range(len(x)): instead and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` and `j` are elements of the lists, not indexes, so it doesn't make sense to use `x[i]`.

Don't put the coordinates in separate lists, use a single list with tuples.

Other issues: You need to append to `distance`, not overwrite it each time through the loop. You need to calculate `perimiter` at the end; you're calculating it when the `perimimter` list is empty.

You don't need to use `abs()`, since you're squaring it, and the square of a negative number is the same as the corresponding positive number.

Instead of checking the index and using `break` to stop before you reach the last index, use a slice to iterate one less time.

```
from math import sqrt
coords = []
distance = []

while True:
    xvalue = int(input('Enter x value of the point: '))
    if xvalue == 0:
        break
    yvalue = int(input('Enter y value of the point: '))
    coords.append((x, y))

for i, (x, y) in coords[:-1]:
    nextx, nexty = coords[i+1]
    distance.append(sqrt((x - nextx)**2 + (y - nexty)**2))

perimiter = sum(distance)
```