# Question surrounding python and euclidean distance calculation

Tags: python, matrix, coordinates, distance

I'm learning python and i'm wondering if someone could help steer me in the right direction. 
I have to write some python code that will randomly generate N (N is how many the user specifies when prompted) points on a 2D plane which I believe I have done:

```
from random import randrange
# Example points in 2-dimensional space...
i = int(input('How many coordinates would you like to generate? \n'))

coords_list = [(randrange(100), randrange(100)) for _ in range(i)]

print(coords_list)
```

This creates a list of coordinate tuples: [(1,2), (3,4)] etc.

The question then asks calculate the distance matrix between these points but I can't use numpy or anything else like that, I have to use a distance function and I've come across a euclidean equation but i'm unsure on how that will help me build the matrix.

If someone could give me some hints or tips I would be very grateful

Many thanks, 
Jack

Comment: See my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61965118/1491895)

Comment: Do you understand what the matrix should look like - i.e., the rule that tells you what the value for each element of the matrix should be? Do you understand how to compute the distance between two points? Do you understand how to iterate over all the pairs of points?

Comment: The question asks me to randomly generates the coordinates of N points on a two-dimensional plane
(the N value should be provided by the user while the program is running),
then calculates the distance matrix between these points (distance should be used)
Euclid; distance calculation should be carried out by the function defined in
program) will solve the traveling salesman problem for the calculated distance matrix and show the optimal route found. Hmm I think I may be able to teach myself to calculate the distance for a pair of values using euclid and then iterate through - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per what I understand through your question is you need to create n Coordinates and then make a distance matrix over all the points in the plane.

You can use scipy is a Python-based ecosystem of open-source software for mathematics, science, and engineering. - [Scipy](https://www.scipy.org/)

This function - [scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html) will hel you to calculate distance between two points in a plane.

And, you can create a loop over it to store it in a matrix to create your distance matrix.

In case I am missing some point from your question please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I'd love to be able to use scipy or something like that but the question specifically says 'distance calculation should be carried out by the function defined in program' which to me seems like I should have mine own function to perform the calculation

Comment: how do you suppose a matrix should look like in this case?                                           
(1,2) (3,1). I know (1,2) to (1,2) would be 0. I'm just struggling to imagine visually how this matrix should look, like columns and rows

Comment: I can see with my randomly generated list of coordinates if I do '''print(coords_list)  I get [(6, 40), (71, 49), (24, 19), (13, 72), (66, 77)] and If I do print(coords_list[0] I get 
(6, 40) 
How would I iterate through and perform the euclidean algorithm on x and y values if they're grouped together as coordinates?